# Handing over variable storing selected list item

Tags: vba, variables, listbox

I might miss just a stupid small detail but I don't get a hang on it.

I've created a userform with a listbox where I want the user to select one item. This is working so far as my variable "termin" has the right value before I close the user form

```
Private Sub OKButton_click()
termin = Eventlist.List(Eventlist.ListIndex)
MsgBox termin             'Just for testing purposes. It gives me the selected item
Unload Eventabfrage
End Sub
```

And this is a part of what I have in 'ThisOutlookSession':

```
Option Explicit
Dim termin As String

Public Sub MailMerge()

    Eventabfrage.Show
    MsgBox termin   'and there it is empty but shouldn't be empty
enter code here

End Sub
```

What do I have to do to hand over the value to my MailMerge Sub?
It is a macro in Outlook so storing it in any Excel cell is not an option.

Comment: Are they both in the same application? if so you need to make `termin` `public termin as string`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks for your reply. They are both in Outlook. I changed it to ```  public termin as string ``` but no improvement with this

Comment: Are you redefining termin elsewhere also?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav No, I don't. It's just once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than using `Public` variable (which I would only as the last chance since it's prone to many drawbacks), you can use `UserForm` class `Tag` property to pass info in and out an instance of a Userform and a more safe Userform instantiating and terminating scheme, as follows:

in the calling module:

```
Public Sub MailMerge()
    Dim termin As String ' declare 'termin' as a Sub scoped variable

    With New Eventabfrage ' get a new instance of the wanted userform class and reference it

        .Show

        termin = .Tag ' retrieve referenced userform 'Tag' property and store it in 'termin' variable

        'enter code here  
    End With ' <-- this will unload the userform instance

End Sub
```

in the `Eventabfrage` class module

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    With Me ' reference the Userform class current instance
        .Tag = .Eventlist.List(.Eventlist.ListIndex)
        .Hide ' hide the userform instead of unloading it, so as to have it "alive", along with its properties (and methods) in its calling sub
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, actually this helpt the problem. However now my checkboxes in the same form do not revognise their true value anymore :-D But I can work with that.